# While using nuxt2.3.x to import async component met error with Reason: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I want to use async component in my page to reduce the vendor file size.
But when I run the page in dev use command `yarn run dev` then redirect to the page with async component I will meet the error:
[Error message snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZSx.png)

```
 ERROR  [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: () => ({                                                  12:20:30
  component: Promise.resolve(/*! import() */).then(__webpack_require__.t.bind(null, /*! jquery */ "jquery", 7)).then($ => $).then($ => Promise.resolve(/*! import() */).then(__webpack_require__.t.bind(null, /*! vue-full-calendar */ "vue-full-calendar", 7))).then(({
    FullCalendar
  }) => FullCalendar)
})
```

Reason: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

My code like this:

```
components: {
FullCalendar: () => ({
  component: import(/* webpackPreload: true */ 'jquery')
    .then($ => $)
    .then($ => import(/* webpackPreload: true */ 'vue-full-calendar'))
    .then(({ FullCalendar }) => FullCalendar),
}),
```

},

So I need help to let me know how to resolve this issue.

BTW, this issue only happened in the dev environment after build the issue will be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve it.
Refer:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/dev/examples/dynamic-components/pages/index.vue

My code:

> HTML

```
...
<component 
 :is="fullcalendar" 
 :config="config" 
 :events="events" />
...
```

> Script

```
...
import { async } from 'q';
...
const components={
    FullCalendar: () => import('jquery')
        .then($ => $)
        .then($ => import('vue-full-calendar'))
        .then(({ FullCalendar }) => FullCalendar)
  }
...
mounted(){
    // load async component
    (async ()=>{
      await components['FullCalendar']();
      this.fullcalendar = 'FullCalendar';
    })()
  }
...
```